# JQ map with parent and child value

Tags: json, jq, parent-child

I have a bunch (hundreds) of JSON files with a parent child structure, e.g.

```
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "TableA",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "FieldA"
        },
        {
          "name": "FieldB"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "TableB",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "FieldA"
        },
        {
          "name": "FieldB"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to add an extra field to the child object containing a value from the parent, e.g.

```
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "TableA",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "FieldA",
          "fqn": "TableA_FieldA"
        },
        {
          "name": "FieldB",
          "fqn": "TableA_FieldB"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "TableB",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "FieldA",
          "fqn": "TableB_FieldA"
        },
        {
          "name": "FieldB",
          "fqn": "TableB_FieldB"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Since there are so many files I'd like to process them automatically, and it feels like this should be doable with JQ, but I can't seem to work out how. Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 2):

Use the update operator `|=` to retain the contexts while storing the `.name` values in variables using `as`:

```bash
.tables[] |= (
  .name as $tname | .fields[] |= (
    .name as $fname | .fqn = "\($tname)_\($fname)"
  )
)
```

```json
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "TableA",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "FieldA",
          "fqn": "TableA_FieldA"
        },
        {
          "name": "FieldB",
          "fqn": "TableA_FieldB"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "TableB",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "FieldA",
          "fqn": "TableB_FieldA"
        },
        {
          "name": "FieldB",
          "fqn": "TableB_FieldB"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UOlvj2t2wIM)

Answer (score 2):

The following is equivalent to @pmf's solution but is perhaps a little less magical (it uses `map` as suggested in the question), and only introduces one variable:

```
.tables |= map( .name as $name | .fields |= map( .fqn = "\($name)_\(.name)" ))
```